# python xml.dom parsing problems

Tags: python, xml, html-parsing

I am writing a program in which the first step takes an `URL` address and opens the page. Then it puts the content into the `xml.dom.minidom` parser:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

page = urllib2.urlopen(page_url)
parser = parse(page)
```

The problem is that a lot of pages have mismatched tags and special characters so the parse method raises error. Also it raises error if there is any `<br>` and not `<br />`...

I tried like this:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

page = urllib2.urlopen(page_url)
data = ""
for line in page.readlines():
    data += str(line.replace("<br>", "<br />").replace(OTHER).replace...)
parser = parse(data)
```

But, this is just not a good solution.

So, is there any lib that is not so sensitive to mismatched tags and other errors in html code?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/), it's very robust, and `lxml` in general is quite fast and has very nice capabilities, including [XPath support](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html).

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.parse('http://example.com')
```

Comment: nop not working. o yea and lxml doesnt have .html package (its only lxml.parse)

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version? [Because it certainly does](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html).